# preg_replace cutting off leading digit

Tags: php, preg-replace

I can get along with regex when needed, but for some reason I am in the dark trying to figure out why preg_replace cuts off leading digit or space.

Example:

```
$phone = '00 385 1234567';
$sig = 'abcd <span id="phone"></span> efgh';
$text = preg_replace('/(<span[^>]*id="phone".*)(.*?)(<\/span>)/smi', '$1'.$phone.'$3', $sig);

echo $text;
```

First 0 is missing in result, also if there is any digit or space (or maybe some other sign as well), but not if first is a character or sign + and others.
Can someone shed some light on this behaviour please?

Comment: Your pattern is a bit "clumsy", since the second group is not matching anything. The current regex can be written as `'/(<span[^>]*id="phone".*)(<\/span>)/si'` and in the replacement you would replace `$3` with `$2`. But to fix the current issue, replace `$1` with `${1}`.

Comment: uf, curly braces fixed my current issue. I need to check out what curly braces are all about :) thanks! ...I know it is a but clumsy, but it worked so far. Will check out your's and improve :) The second group is not matching anything in this example, but can be nothing or anything in real case. Please post your comment as answer. Thank you!

Comment: It is a duplicate and I closed the question. Note that your Group 2 will **never** match any text because `.*` before it will grab all the text it can and there will be nothing left for `(.*?)`.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks! Will correct.